# php adds backslash when printing quoted value but i dont want it to do that

Tags: php, mysql, magic-quotes

In my database, there is a value something like that:

```
i haven't done it yet.
```

p.s: in the database the value is exactly the same here, there is no backslash.

When I print it php adds backslash before ' single quote.
`get_magic_quotes_gpc` is off.
I dont understand why it is putting a backslash.

here is my php code to print value :

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = $_POST['foo'];
echo $_SESSION['foo'];
```

Comment: Are you viewing your database with phpmyadmin? Maybe php myadmin is stripping the slashes but it really is there, try echo stripslashes($blah));

Comment: yes i view with phpmyadmin, i dont know maybe there is. But before i change my server, it wasnt like that.

Comment: How are you populating `$value`?

Comment: @Murat But you said the value is in your database and you're getting it from `$_POST`. Is it really in your database or is it just submitted by the user?

Comment: Or `get_magic_quotes_gpc` are not off, or in DB your value is `i haven\'t done it yet.`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
echo stripslashes($value));
```

Comment: That may fix the symptom, but not the underlying problem :)

Comment: yes, i know stripslashes but the point is that why it puts backslashes while magic_quotes_gpc is off.

Comment: Are you using mysql_real_escape_string() or anything like that? Without seeing the code your using to insert the data it's anyones guess. Harsh mark down btw

Comment: Having characters escaped is not a problem, it's a good thing.

Comment: i realized that when i post the value to store in database , i set it to the session then i print it from session so the problem is php not mysql.

Comment: This is actually quite interesting I've never had this happen to me before.